# Windows credentials not being passed to api using Postman (Windows version)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, postman

I just installed the Windows app version of Postman. Previously I have been using the Chrome plugin. It seems the Windows version is not passing through my Windows credentials to my ASP.Net Web API application. I get 401.2 errors.

The same exact call works fine from the Chrome plugin.

Is there a configuration I am missing perhaps?

Thank you
Karl

Comment: Just wanted to throw a #metoo on this.  They are really pushing us to stop using the Chrome extension.  No matter what i set credentials to on the desktop version, I cannot get it to pass my default windows credentials.